# Wrong resize of RadioButtons in JavaFX WebView

Tags: java, javafx, zooming

When I zoom in on a web page opened in a WebView (zoom factor < 1.0), most of the content gets scaled as expected, however there are some things that do not, like radio buttons or check boxes:

[image]

In the above image the first WebView is unzoomed and the second has a zoom factor of 0.5 though the radio buttons have (or have nearly) the same size.
Here is the code for this example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class WebViewScalingDemo2 extends Application {
  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    stage.setTitle("HTML");
    stage.setWidth(800);
    stage.setHeight(800);
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
    final VBox root = new VBox();



    String html = "<html><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"><title>Radio-Buttons definieren</title><style>"+
    "fieldset{"+ 
      "border:none;"+
    "}</style></head>"+
"<body><h1>Hier wird abkassiert!</h1><form action=\"#\"><p>Geben Sie Ihre Zahlungsweise an:</p>"+ 
    "<fieldset><input type=\"radio\" id=\"mc\" name=\"Zahlmethode\" value=\"Mastercard\"><label for=\"mc\"> Mastercard</label><br>"+ 
      "<input type=\"radio\" id=\"vi\" name=\"Zahlmethode\" value=\"Visa\"><label for=\"vi\">  Visa</label><br>"+ 
      "<input type=\"radio\" id=\"ae\" name=\"Zahlmethode\" value=\"AmericanExpress\"><label for=\"ae\"> American Express</label>"+ 
    "</fieldset></form></body></html>";

    WebView webView1 = new WebView();
    webView1.setPrefSize(300, 300);
    webView1.setLayoutX(250);
    webView1.setLayoutY(250);
    webView1.getEngine().loadContent(html);
    WebView webView2 = new WebView();
    webView2.setPrefSize(300, 300);
    webView2.setLayoutX(250);
    webView2.setLayoutY(250);
    webView2.getEngine().loadContent(html);

    root.getChildren().addAll(webView1, webView2);


    webView1.setZoom(1);
    webView2.setZoom(0.5);

    scene.setRoot(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

For me this is an issue because there are labels close to the right of the buttons, and if the zoom factor is too low, the label will be partially over the radio button.

I have two questions here:

1. Why are the radio buttons not scaled properly? They also stay the same size when using a zoom factor > 1.0.
2. Is there anything I can do about this? I was thinking along the lines of some CSS I could indject to force larger spacing when the zoom is low, but that would be dependent on the used zoom factor and it should be a solution that works for all radio buttons and check boxes, without the need to target them specially (by id or style class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with the native code, the rendering with webkit in javafx and is still present in Java **1.8.0_60**.

The workaround is to apply `-webkit-transform: scale(**your scale here**);` on this elements on your own.

If you don't intend to change the `zoomProperty` dynamically I suggest adding **CSS** style:

```
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
  -webkit-transform: scale(**your scale here**);
}
```

The other approach is with **javascript** and is good if you intend to change the `zoomProperty` dynamically:

```
(function($){ 
   var scaleCheckboxesAndRadioButtons = function(scale) {
     var $elements= $('input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"]');
     $elements.css("-webkit-transform", "scale(" + scale + ")");
  }
}(jQuery));
```

Than just add a listener on the zoomProperty of your webview and on change call the javascript function from your java code:

```
webView.zoomProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
  webView.getEngine().executeScript("scaleCheckboxesAndRadioButtons(" + newValue + ");");
});
```

Comment: Your Answer helped me. Thanks a lot.