# Java, JavaFx : Inserting a HTML&JS(static,no internet) project inside a JavaFX container

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, javafx-2, containers

I am working on a task in which we need to put one of our HTML & JS based project inside a JavaFX project or any other suitable containers which are out there. The purpose is to create an app, which can directly be deployed and would prevent any users from checking out the source code of HTML & JS.

Some time back when I was checking out JavaFX, I read that it supports JS, and JS can be used with it. Is there any way to create a container inside which I can put my HTML&JS files by giving path, etc?

How can I go about this? Whatever I am trying to do, what is it called. Any help, pointers, suggestions, would be nice.

*Initial test*

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private Scene scene;
    MyBrowser myBrowser;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test web");

        myBrowser = new MyBrowser();
        scene = new Scene(myBrowser, 1920, 1200);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}


class MyBrowser extends Region {

    final String hellohtml = "hello.html";

    WebView webView = new WebView();
    WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();

    public MyBrowser(){

        URL urlHello = getClass().getResource("hello.html");
        webEngine.load(urlHello.toExternalForm());

        getChildren().add(webView);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to load the HTML and corresponding JS from a local source e.g. packaged with the application and not call a URL in the web?

Comment: [`WebView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html)?

Comment: @hotzst : Exactly... :-) And package the html&JS in the application, this way, the HTML&JS should be in classpath is what I thought. Sounds okay till now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @sillyfly suggested use a `WebView`:

```
File f = new File(..);
// ..
final WebView webview = new WebView();
webview.getEngine().load(f.toURI().toURL().toString());
```

The hard part for me is always to figure out the right location to be used to reference the file.

Another option is when you have the HTML in the form of a string to load that as content:

```
String html = ...
webview.getEngine().loadcontent(html)
```

Be sure to check out at least the JavaDoc on [`WebView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) and [`WebEngine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html)`

Comment: We are worried about the paths of the JS and CSS files inside. Also we have a little resolution problem(Link : http://s28.postimg.org/o23em5ylp/Screenshot_from_2016_01_15_10_31_22.png). Can you see the main post, where we are doing our browser settings. The region inside browser size and the browser size to be same, in potrait mode. Any ideas about that?

Comment: Basically the size of the `WebView` is defined by the size of the content. There are some ways you can influence that. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036560/wrong-resize-of-radiobuttons-in-javafx-webview. The paths should not be a problem as long as they are relative and all the referenced resources are packaged and at its proper location. You might also take a look at [willow browser](https://code.google.com/p/willow-browser/) at least for inspiration.

Comment: No, I am not talking about scaling, the size of the region inside, the white area, it is not the same as the size of browser. Like when you open Firefox, you don't see the gray area because site is small. That's what I meant. I am not much an UI expert, maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Hi, I have started a separate post for UI problem at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808476/java-javafx-setting-browser-region-size-position-properly-and-use-default-pr  . Can you please check it out. Thank you. :-)